# Jquery - Apply class to highest value multiple times

Tags: jquery, highlight

I have the following table structure which results come from two seperate php queries.

```
<tr>
<td>Item 1</td>
<td>&pound;<?=$row1['item_1']?></td>
<td>&pound;<?=$row2['item_1']?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Item 2</td>
<td>&pound;<?=$row1['item_2']?></td>
<td>&pound;<?=$row2['item_2']?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Item 3</td>
<td>&pound;<?=$row1['item_3']?></td>
<td>&pound;<?=$row2['item_3']?></td>
</tr>
```

What I'm trying to do is within each row highlight the highest number pulled from the database.

Any help is appreciated!

UPDATE

I've added the following code to the page but can't for the life of me get it working. I can see it working on jsFiddle but I must be doing something wrong. Help please

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js "></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    $.fn.max = function(callback) {
        var max = null,
            maxIndex = null;

        this.each(function() {
            var value = callback.call(this);
            if (+value === value) {
                if (!max || value > max) {
                    max = value;
                    maxIndex = $(this).index();
                }
            }

        });
        return max !== null ? this.eq(maxIndex) : $();
    };
}(jQuery));


$('tr').each(function() {
    $(this).children('td').max(function() {
        var value = +$(this).text().substr(1);
        if (!isNaN(value)) {
            return value;
        }
    }).addClass('red');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please post the generated HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have numbers of the format `x.xx`:

**Update:** I might be even better to create a plugin for that. Something like:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.max = function(callback) {
        var max = null,
            maxIndex = null;

        this.each(function() {
            var value = callback.call(this);
            if (+value === value) {
                if (!max || value > max) {
                    max = value;
                    maxIndex = $(this).index();
                }
            }

        });
        return max !== null ? this.eq(maxIndex) : $();
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Which can then be used as:

```
$('tr').each(function() {
    $(this).children('td').max(function() {
        var value = +$(this).text().substr(1);
        if (!isNaN(value)) {
            return value;
        }
    }).addClass('highlight');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuLBS/1/)

---

**Old answer:**

```
$('tr').each(function() {
    var $tds = $(this).children('td'),
        max = null,
        maxIndex = null;

    $tds.each(function() {
        var value = +$(this).text().substr(1);
        if(!isNaN(value)) {
            if(!max || value > max) {
                max = value;
                maxIndex = $(this).index();
            }
        }
    });
    if(maxIndex !== null) {
        $tds.eq(maxIndex).addClass('highlight');
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuLBS/2/)

Comment: I like the plugin idea. I forked and made some mods: one to take a callback to parse the content, another callback to execute, and finally, it returns the original set for chainability.
http://jsfiddle.net/zuLBS/8/

Comment: Cheers for that, demo is exactly what I'm after.

I've tried it on my page but can't get it working. Do I need a certain version of Jquery? Does it matter that the results are being pulled from a database and not static within the html code?

Comment: @LinusIT: You need at least jQuery 1.4. It does not matter where the data comes from. Important is the generated HTML.

Comment: @Felix King: HTML Output: `code`<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="data"> <tr> <td>DBW</td> <td>&pound;85</td> <td>&pound;54</td> </tr> <tr> <td>GBW</td> <td>&pound;2</td> <td>&pound;897</td></tr></table>

Answer (score 0):

You could do (but could be done much better i think):

```
Array.max = function(array) {
    return Math.max.apply(Math, array);
};

Array.keyPosition = function(array, value) {
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] === value) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


$('table tr').each(function() {
    var numbers = [];
    $(this).children('td').each(function(i, el) {
        var number = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
        if (isNaN(number)){
            number = -1;
        }
        numbers.push(number);
    });
    var max = Array.max(numbers);
    var index = Array.keyPosition(numbers, max);
    $(this).find('td:eq('+index+')').css('background-color', 'yellow');

});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/DYUaP/